# How do I set up a mail server on a Linode VPS?

Tags: email, mail-server

i have a linode account and trying to setup an email server where i can send and receive email from my registered domain.

i typed this into shell:
sudo tasksel install mail-server

but what is the next step?

Answer (score 6):

Running a mailserver is not a install-and-go process. Over time you'll want to deal with spam and viruses and people trying to hack your machine via the mail servers. Despite hosting dozens of domains, I don't host email *at all*. I've farmed all of that off to Google Mail and I recommend everybody does something similar.

Life is too short to worry about your email server twice a day.

---

But assuming you still want to install a mail server, you'll want to follow the proper guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer

The short version is:

- Install MTA (eg: Postfix) and configure it to allow mail in for your domain
- Install MDA (eg: Dovecot) to allow people to collect their mail

Comment: i did a clean install and followed this guide: http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-10.04-lucid#sph_set-the-hostname

Comment: +1 for Life is too short to worry about your email server twice a day.

Comment: If you need to setup an email server quickly, this might help: https://mailinabox.email/guide.html